# How to not print state changes in console

Tags: reactjs

My console is displaying all these values and I am not printing it using console.log . How to remove these from the console in order to keep the console clean.

I believe they are coming from the response.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are generated by a redux-middleware called 'redux-logger'. Just remove it from your middlewares when creating your store.